# XMLSQLQuery queried by PHP

Tags: php, xpath, xsd, wsdl

When one makes a search for XMLSQLQuery on stack overflow, 0 results are found. So I really hope someone can help.

I have a link to a WSDL file that supports XMLXPathQuery *(I'm not experienced in using WSDL files, and never done XMLSQLQuery before, only standard SOAP calls from a standard PHP soapclient)*

I also have a username and a password and database name.

In theory I can run an xmlsqlquery that looks like this: `"select lastname from users where statusflag = 1 for xml auto"`

BUT how do I connect (with username, password and dbname) to this WSDL file that supports XMLSQLQuery and how do I run a query, in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone other looking, it looks like the WSDL file has the main call-functions like:

```
<s:element name="StringXPathQuery">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XPathExpression" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DBName" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

(correctly positioned not like here)

So one can use SoapClient in PHP. BUT the fields are not in the WSDL file, so one can guess or try to get some documentation about that.

Example:

```
$client = new SoapClient("some wsdl url");
$user = $client->StringXPathQuery(array(
    'XPathExpression' => 'user[@lastname="Hans"]',
    'Username' => 'some username',
    'Password' => 'some password',
    'DBName' => 'some db name'
  ));
```